# Java highest score

Tags: java, for-loop

Okay so i'm trying to make a program to display the top 2 highest scorers of 5 students only.

So sample output.

```
Enter your name : Spear
Enter score : 56

Enter your name : Sky
Enter score : 61

Enter your name : Spy
Enter score : 45

Enter your name : Raks
Enter score : 31

Enter your name : Felicio
Enter score : 39


Congratulations Sky!
Congratulations Spear!
```

I only know how to take the largest score and not the second here is what i got so far.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Highest{
    public static void main(String[]args) {

        Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name = "";
        int score;
        int k;
        int highest = 0;

        num = x.nextLine();
        largest = num;

        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter name: ");
            k = x.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Enter score: ");
            num = x.nextInt();
            if (num > highest) {
                highest = num;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(largest);
    }
} // how do i display the name of the highest score and the second placer?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to look at sorting methods to solve such problems in the future e.g. [sorting Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(int[])) and [sorting collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html)

For your particular case where you want to select the two max elements you can simply use two variables

```
int highestScore = 0;
String highestName = "";

int secondScore = 0;
String secondName = "";
```

and then

```
if (num > highestScore) {
    secondScore = highestScore;
    secondName = highestName;

    highestScore = num;
    highestName = name;
} else if (num > secondScore) {
    secondScore = num;
    secondName = name;
}
```

The code may be cleaner if you define a Student class to hold score and name.

Printing is straightforward

```
System.out.printnl("Congratulations " + highestName + "!");
System.out.printnl("Congratulations " + secondName + "!");
```

Comment: How do i print their names?

Comment: i think i have a logical error in my for loop on how to keep their names.

Comment: Should i create an array for the names? because when i type the first name then i go to type the second i cant.

Comment: can you please show me how to do the for loop for this i keep getting an error on asking to enter their names and score

Comment: @Jake In order to get a line as a string with a `Scanner` you must wait until a line has been input and then retrieve the line. e.g. in your for loop `if (x.hasNextLine()) { name = x.nextLine(); }`

Comment: @Jake same with score `if (x.hasNextInt()) { num = x.nextInt(); }`

Answer (score 1):

To expand on what Manos said:

You probably want to create a class for your students:

```
class Student {
    private String name;
    private int score;

    Student(String name, int score) {
        this.name = name;
        this.score = score;
    }

    public int getScore() {
        return this.score;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

You can then add each student to a collection and use a Comparator to sort your students:

```
Collections.sort(students, new Comparator<Student>() {
    public int compare(Student o1, Student o2) {
        return Integer.compare(o1.getScore(), o2.getScore());
    }
});
```

The resulting collection will hold a list where the highest scoreing students will be at the far end of the collection, or you can then reverse the collection so they are at the begining instead:

```
Collections.reverse(students);
```

Full example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    class Student {
        private String name;
        private int score;

        Student(String name, int score) {
            this.name = name;
            this.score = score;
        }

        public int getScore() {
            return this.score;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }
    }

    ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        java.util.Random rand = new java.util.Random();
        Student s = new Student("Student " + i, rand.nextInt());
        students.add(s);
    }

    Collections.sort(students, new Comparator<Student>() {
        public int compare(Student o1, Student o2) {
            return Integer.compare(o1.getScore(), o2.getScore());
        }
    });
    Collections.reverse(students);


    System.out.println("Highest scoring student: " + students.get(0).getName() + " with a score of " + students.get(0).getScore());
    System.out.println("Highest scoring student: " + students.get(1).getName() + " with a score of " + students.get(1).getScore());

    // List all students (Java 8 only...)
    students.forEach( x -> System.out.println("Name: " + x.getName() + " with score: " + x.getScore()) );
}
```